# Passing parameters to included SDF

Tags: gazebo-model, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For example I have a bunch of identical cameras in a world. The model of a camera includes the `gazebo_ros_camera` plugin with parameters such as topic name etc. Obviously every camera should publish to the topic with unique name. So, is it possible to pass such parameters from within `<include>` tag? If not, are there any workarounds? Duplicating the camera model with modified parameters is not a nice option.

Something similar to `<arg>` tag in ROS' launch files would suffice, but I was unable to find anything like this in SDF specification.

**EDIT**:

Let's say I have a Gazebo model of camera:

```
<sdf version="1.3">
  <model name="camera">
    <link name="link">
      ...
      <sensor name="camera" type="camera">
        ...
        <plugin name="camera_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
          ...
          <!-- PROBLEMS ARE HERE -->
          <imageTopicName>image_raw</imageTopicName>
          <cameraName>camera</cameraName>
          ...
          <frameName>camera_frame</frameName>
          ...
        </plugin>
      </sensor>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

Now, if I include several of these to a world:

```
<sdf version="1.3">
  <world name="cameras_world">
    ...
    <include>
      <uri>model://camera</uri>
      <name>camera_1</name>
      <pose>1 0 1 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>

    <include>
      <uri>model://camera</uri>
      <name>camera_2</name>
      <pose>2 0 1 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>

    <include>
      <uri>model://camera</uri>
      <name>camera_3</name>
      <pose>3 0 1 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>
</sdf>
```

All three cameras will publish to ***exactly*** same ROS topic: `/camera/image_raw` as well as with ***exactly*** same frame ID: `camera_frame`. Because there is no way on SDF level to pass down custom parameters to included models.

So I need a workaround for this and looking for your kind suggestions.

I hope now my question is clear :-)

Thanks,

Boris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2764/passing-parameters-to-included-sdf/) by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-05-10

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vangelis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4013/vangelis/) on 2017-10-25**:
@boris did you find a solution after all these years? I face this problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

See the [drc_vehicle model](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/611fc562e081a51723a2a0038a1ad4842b87c643/gazebo_models/environments/drc_vehicle/model.sdf) as an example for how to use included models with plugins.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-05-12**:
I have multiple instances of `model-with-sensor-plugin.sdf` included into a `world.sdf`. If I understand correctly you refer to MudPlugin, which instead of being put inside the Polaris Ranger EV model is on higher level of hierarchy. However in this case plugin should be aware on how to subscribe to particular Gazebo sensor, e.g. using tag <contact_sensor_name>. I am using standard ROS plugins that do not have such interface, so I need a more generic approach.

**Comment by [ricardo.halfeld](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21920/ricardo.halfeld/) on 2020-06-11**:
This link is now broken.

**Comment by [brawner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/12/brawner/) on 2022-09-20**:
Fixed [github link](https://github.com/osrf/drcsim/tree/master/drcsim_model_resources/gazebo_models/drc_vehicle).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

you could add the `<topic>` as a parameter to the plugin (similarly to [this](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2058/how-to-control-publish-rate-in-ros-enabled-plugins/) answer):

```
<plugin name='plugin_name' filename='libplugin_name.so'>
    <topic>topic_name</topic>
</plugin>
```

in the plugin:

```
void PluginName::Load(physics::ModelPtr _parent, sdf::ElementPtr _sdf)
...
string topic;

if (!_sdf->HasElement("topic"))
{
    // if parameter tag does NOT exist
    std::cout << "Missing parameter <topic> in PluginName, default to standard" << std::endl;
    topic = "standard";
}
    // if parameter tag exists, get its value
else topic = _sdf->GetElement("topic")->GetValueString();
```

Cheers,
Andrei

UPDATE!!!

You could use the [GetName()](http://gazebosim.org/api/1.5.0/classgazebo_1_1rendering_1_1Camera.html#a71e0863d59f34834e4583cb0c29d4d04) function to get the names of each camera from the `<name>` tag, and use that as a unique key for the topics name.

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-05-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/164/boris/) on 2013-05-11**:
I can't use this method unless I rewrite every single third-party plugin. Obviously I don't want to spend time on this.

**Comment by [reubenjohn](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2843/reubenjohn/) on 2016-09-27**:
Can the same be done with urdf? If so, how would the c++ code change?